# Re-indexing a DataFrame with a composite index

Tags: pandas, dataframe, python-3.6

I had to load my DataFrame from a text file using the 'index_col=False' option to avoid an offset between the headers and the records.

Now that the DataFrame has been properly loaded and cleaned,I need to reindex according to a key that is composed of the first 4 columns.

Q1: recommended option: should I create an additional column with the composite key or is there a more efficient alternative ?
Q2: if I need to reindex according to a composite key, any hint on how to do that in a DataFrame ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YOu can simply put the 4 columns in your index with `set_index([col1,col2,col3,col4],inplace=True)`. You can refer to the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html
You can also add the option `verify_integrity=True` if you want to check the uniqueness of your index.